# Usage of JWT after logout

Tags: security, session, authentication, authorization, jwt

I have a query, is it possible to use current JWT after the user is logged out?

Scenario: I have a set of private APIs that needs authorization token to access the endpoints. Here I have a web application where I need to log in and get the JWT. I keep the token aside and from the active session I press the logout button and my session is needed to expiry even though I am able to use the JWT to access the endpoints, how will this happening is this the right approach or can I raise this as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***How this is happening?***

The session details might be stored in JWT itself and there is no server side state for the same. Every time you are sending the JWT, they are trying to decrypt it, then validating the claims present in it and providing the required access. Since, the JWT itself contains its expiry information, they are unable to invalidate it. It will be expired after specified time decided at the time of token creation. They might be just clearing the cookie at the time of logout.

***Is this the right approach?***

Depends. It's tradeoff between speed and security. In order to revoke the token access, there should be a server state maintaining the set of access/revoked tokens. If the application is not storing any confidential/sensitive information, its a design call for them to opt for a server state. If the site is on https and free from XSS, the only way to get the token somehow is by gaining physical access to the device. If the expiry time of access token is less than 20 min, the risk is minimal. But it mostly depends on the nature of application. For example, this is not a right approach for a banking application.

***Can I raise a bug?***

You should to confirm the hypothesis. There can be a possibility that they actually have an infrastructure to revoke the access tokens but its faulty as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chaitanya,
1.Here in my case, the access token is valid for 10hours, I guess its too high and it is vulnerable to Stored XSS.
2.This is not the banking application, it is workforce management where all the worker's details and work artifacts stored and approved higher privileges user.

Am concluding this as a bug because the API calls are passed to the server through unencrypted channel i.e, HTTP.